# the context of part of sentence

Tags: context

If they go for it, I think Spurs will score on Saturday, it is just what else happens at the other end that is the worry for Pochettino' side.

I don't understand the context of this sentence.

Comment: Your quote comes from the end of http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42358472 The context is Tottenham Hotspur playing away against Premier League leaders Manchester City, and the possibility of Manchester City scoring a lot of goals given that Tottenham's defence could be stronger than it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m sure you know that ‘Spurs’ is short for ‘Tottenham Hotspurs’, the Premier Division football club, based in North London.

A sports commentator is predicting how a forthcoming match will go.

The thing to notice is that although he or she is talking about a future game, he or she is using what we normally think of as the present tense.  This is common in English and in other European languages.  But that is more of an ELU matter.